# Is “Not to generalize or anything” an idiomatic parenthesis?

Tags: phrases

September 18 Time magazine’s [article](http://swampland.time.com/2012/09/18/how-mitt-romneys-luck-ran-out/) titled “How Mitt Romney’s Luck Ran Out” introduced GOP Presidential nominee Mitt Romney’s observation covertly recorded at a Florida fundraiser to the effect that:

> ... the 47% of Americans who pay no federal income taxes will never vote for him because they "believe they are victims" entitled to endless government support and will never "take personal responsibility and care for their lives.”

It is followed by this sentence:

> *Not to generalize or anything*. *This,* just days after Romney’s rash statement late on the night of Sept. 11 suggesting that the Obama Administration sympathized with the violent mobs in Cairo and Benghazi.

What does “*Not to generalize or anything*” mean? Doesn’t “Not to generalize” suffice? Is “or anything” necessary? Is this a common idiomatic phrase, or parenthesis?

In passing, I don’t find a verb that explains what “*This*” that follows “Not to generalize or anything” in the above excerpt. What is the predicate of “This”?

Comment: [Not to be rude or anything](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22not+to+be+rude+or+anything%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but I don't think *"Not to generalize or anything."* can properly be seen as a valid "sentence", so it's clunky writing to start with. But I imagine the word *"This"* simply refers to Romney's unguarded comments on the 47% of Americans whose votes he will never get. Especially not after appearing to be dismissive of them anyway. Parse it as *"This [gaffe] **comes** just days after Romney's [previous gaffe]"*

Comment: Sorry, but I think it's just Too Localised. This just weeks after I voted to close another of your questions for the same reason. It's an unusual stylised form that you're more likely to hear from an enthusiastic sports commentator on the TV/radio than to see in formal writing. Essentially it's a way of adding "immediacy" to the delivery, where *"this"* means *"this [thing which I'm talking about now] should be considered in the context of [something else]"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I always appreciate your valuable answers and comments. The big trouble for non-native speakers like me is that we cannot tell whether the particular expression is well-received expression that I can introduce in my conversation and writing (to make it look more ‘native-English-like-style’), or not, because dictionaries don’t teach it. English language site is the only source I can resort to in getting clue and guidance for it. Even if it looks too localized, it’s important for me to know that it’s too localized or unusual expression for a non-native English speaker to adopt.

Comment: No worries. Mine's only one vote, so if anyone thinks there's anything to add they can still answer. It's not impossible to use this construction in conversation, but it's often/usually dismissive or negative in some way. Husband to wife: *"Honey, I think you spend too much money on clothes."* Wife: *"This from a man who spends more on beer in a week than I spend on clothes in a month!"*

Comment: Making "Not to generalize or anything" a stand-alone sentence is typical of people who write like they talk, a popular strategy in the 1970s to help students with writer's block overcome it. But the rest of the strategy was to edit the writing to make it fluent and readable. Imitate **good** writers, not **hack** writers. How can you tell the difference? Ask someone whose judgments about English writing you can trust. They probably don't write for _Time_ or _People_, most local newspapers, or Internet blogs. Popular culture is always 下級の.

Comment: @Bill Franke. Can you explain me what students with ‘writer’s block’ mean?

Comment: @YoichiOishi: It's when a teacher asks a student to write an essay and the student says "I can't think of anything to say". In Pirsig's _Zen & the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance_, Pirsig tells a student who couldn't write an essay to sit in front of a brick building and describe each brick, starting in the upper left corner. After 50 or more sentences, suddenly she's unblocked and writing essays even longer than my answers: the words flow like Niagara and she no longer has writer's block.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I strongly disagree. Explaining idiomatic phrases that one could reasonable come across in fairly common publications is 100 % on topic and not "too localised". Further I should like to add that I, like everyone else here, think Yoichi's questions are always great and probably helpful to other people.

Comment: @Cerberus: There is no "idiomatic phrase" to speak of. Not to be rude or anything (and not to repeat myself?!), but surely my first comment dealt with that. Yoichi also asked peripherally about *"this"*, which *is* an idiomatic usage - but that's hardly come up, has it?

Comment: *Not to **x** or anything* is just something you say before you're about to do exactly that. For instance, *Not to be rude or anything, but [insert rude comment]*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, *not to x or anything* is followed by a *but*, like this:

> Not to generalise, but women often spend too much on shoes they never wear.

Here, it is short for *[I do/did] not [mean] to generalise, but...* It is a caveat, and a warning that what you are about to do (or have just done) may be interpreted in a bad way.

In casual speech, *or anything* is often tacked on to make the generalisation seem less explicit, less important, as in: "I may be generalising here, or I may be doing something else—it doesn't matter anyway—, but...".

Using *not to x or anything* without a following *but* looks like sloppy writing to me for a serious article, which is probably part of the reason why it confused you: the generalising statement ought to follow, explaining the caveat—but no such statement follows here, at least not immediately. It is not a grave sin, but it's not exactly eloquent here. Most writers would only use that in a very casual context.

Based on the rest of the article, I believe the generalisation is supposed to be the writer's theory that "[m]ore recently, however, Romney’s luck has turned", as mentioned at the start of the paragraph. The statement by Romney about the 47 % is supposed to be an example supporting the theory. But *at the same time* it is probably a sarcastic quip referring to Romney's own generalisations in these quotations.

The *this* that comes immediately after is unrelated to the *not to generalise*: it refers to the 47 % statement, the example supporting the theory. It is short for something like *this [was/happened]*, or *[and notice how] this [was]*. It is meant to make clear that there is a connection between the previous example and what follows, Romney's statement about Obama.

Comment: "I believe the generalisation is the writer's theory..." - I disagree.  *Not to generalize or anything* is surely a sarcastic quip referring to what Romney was just quoted as saying, where he generalized about 47% of Americans.

Comment: @Cerberus.I understood that ‘This’ refers to Romney’s remark of 47% of Americans who he thinks ‘pay no federal income taxes and never take personal responsibility and care for their lives.’ But it doesn’t resolve my question about what follows ‘This.’ – What is the predicate of ‘This’? This line still looks to me lacking something.

Comment: @YoichiOichi This sentence "This, just days after Romney’s rash statement late on the night of Sept. 11 suggesting that the Obama Administration sympathized with the violent mobs in Cairo and Benghazi." is typical of contemporary academic prose. To make it a grammatical sentence, "suggesting" has to be changed to "suggested" or "suggests". You're right about the lack of a predicate: there's no main verb, only a gerund ("suggesting") and a subordinate verb, "sympathized". As I said above: "hack writer who writes like he talks" -- and he doesn't talk well.

Comment: @Jez: Now that you mention it, he is probably doing that too. Edited.

Comment: @YoichiOishi: Yes, "this" lacks a main verb. That's why I suggested that you should "was" or "happened": *this happened just days after Romney’s rash statement...*

Comment: I think @cerberus has explained the nuances in tone very well here.  I find myself learning an awful lot about the language just by reading yoichi-oishi's questions!

Comment: @marccenedella: Thanks! I like Yoichi's questions too, and I think Fumble Fingers is wrong in his comments above.